# Flexslider - first thumbnail flashes over screen before page loads on refresh

Tags: tabs, icons, onload, page-refresh, flexslider

I'm a jQuery noobe trying to use Flexslider on a client's site. The show works well except that on load or page refresh, the first thumbnail splashes across the screen very large and pixelated. Only for an instant, then the slideshow works.

The site is at: [Slideshow example](http://www.dev.ronmclegg.com/gallery_1.php)

Comment: A piece of slideshow initilization code might help.

Comment: Please try and create a small reproducable example; external sites have a tendency to disappear making your question useless to future visitors.